# Creating a page that is dependant on the model id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a create product page that takes infomation like name description. I want to make another page that allows the user to add a photo. To that product page. So i created a method for this page.

```
  def pics
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @photo = Photo.new
    @product.photos.build
  end
```

And also i added this to the config file

```
  resources :products do
    collection do
      get :pics
    end
  end
```

And my rake routes look like this.

```
          pics_products GET    /products/pics(.:format)               products#pics
               products GET    /products(.:format)                    products#index
                        POST   /products(.:format)                    products#create
            new_product GET    /products/new(.:format)                products#new
           edit_product GET    /products/:id/edit(.:format)           products#edit
                product GET    /products/:id(.:format)                products#show
                        PUT    /products/:id(.:format)                products#update
                        DELETE /products/:id(.:format)                products#destroy
```

Right now it's not taking the ID of the product it's in. How can i turn it into `pics_products GET    /products/:id/pics(.:format)`?

Comment: Try removing `collection do ... end` and make it just `get :pics`?

Comment: so i did what you said and rake routes gives me /products/:product_id/pics(.:format)   but when i go to localhost/products/125/pics i get Couldn't find Product without an ID

Comment: The id would be in `params[:product_id]` according to the routes output you pasted.

Comment: ^ that worked btw. Make it an answer so i can mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change you routes like this:

```
  resources :products do
    member do
      get :pics
    end
  end
```